# I tried using cx_Freeze to create an exe put it just closes on launch with no error mesages

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I used this setup code I found and changed it and it successfully imported everything but the exe just opens and immediately closes on launch.

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("pygameVideo15.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="A bit Racey",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame","...."],
                           "include_files":["racecar.png","......"]}},
    executables = executables

    )
```

Comment: Build executable with `-c` flag to see error in console window

Comment: Do you think any of the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+cx_freeze+closes) about this on stackoverflow could help you?